# How to get received/sent transactions from bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

I have configured bitcoin core daemon. Using JSON-RPC I want to build web wallet. This why I need list of all incoming/outgoing transactions.

**listtransactions** returns only incoming transactions.

Questions:

1. How to get outgoing & incoming transactions?
2. In **listtransactions** field address - is it receiver or sender?
3. If I can't get outgoing transactions using **listtransactions**, why here is may be three categories like "move", "receive" and "send"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in provided account. When I set it to "*" all transactions was received.

**Wrong**
`listtransactions('my_account', 100)`

**Right**
`listtransactions('*', 100)`

Comment: But why is sent transaction not shown when label is provided? That doesnt make any sense..

Answer (score 0):

For getting listtransactions of bitcoind server command is 
bitcoin-cli listtransactions (This command will return last 10 transactions)
bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" 100 0 (This command will return last 100 transactions here 0 to 100 transactions)